# Link formatting with internal links CSS

Tags: html, css

Basic question here...trying to figure out how to format links with fonts and colors and make them clickable. I was able to get the fonts and colors to look the way I wanted them to when I used this code, but I wasn't able to make the clickable:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif color: #888888; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"><a conversion="true" href="${1://SurveyURL}" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color:#888888; text-decoration: underline" target="_blank">What do you think?</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

But I can make the links clickable, but not get the formatting I want if I use the following code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif color: #888888; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);"><span style="color:#888888;">${l://SurveyLink?d=What%20do%20you%20think?}</span></td>
    </tr>
```

What am I missing to get my formatting to work and also make the link clickable to the survey? (SurveyURL and SurveyLink actually use the same reference FYI) Thanks.

Comment: you should use js
see this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071967/adding-an-onclick-function-to-go-to-url-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071967/adding-an-onclick-function-to-go-to-url-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an onclick function to go to url in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071967/adding-an-onclick-function-to-go-to-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a semicolon on your `font-family` style:

```
<style>
  .tableLink a  { color: #888888;}
</style>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); text-decoration: underline;">
        <span class="tableLink">${l://SurveyLink?d=What%20do%20you%20think?}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed the semi-colon. I ran the code and it is working now, except that the color of the link is still showing as blue vs #888888 before being clicked.

Comment: You will probably have to add `style="color: #888888;"` to your `span` element (see updated code above).

Comment: I updated the code, but it looks like it kept the blue color

Comment: Since your `a` tag is dynamically generated, you'll probably have to add a class to that span `<span class="tableLink">` and put this CSS on your page: `.tableLink a  { color: #888888;}`

Answer (score 0):

The link is clickable, but you did forget a semicolon after `font-family: Arial, sans-serif` which means the rest of the styling didn't apply.

I'm not sure what the link is you're directing to (`${1://SurveyURL}`), but it is clickable for sure.

```css
.link {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #888888;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

a {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #888888;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:500px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="link" colspan="2">
        <a conversion="true" href="${1://SurveyURL}" target="_blank">What do you think?</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```