# Not detecting afterprint from PDF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, printing

I have received a **PDF** from a server in which the user often wants to print without really looking at it. I try to use an `onafterprint` event to close the window, however, it foes not seem to get triggered when I open a PDF this way. If I instead set the URL blank to open an empty page it seems to work just fine.

```js
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let printWindow = window.open(url);
printWindow.onafterprint = function(){
  console.log("afterprint")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't get executed since the pdf window MIME type is "application/pdf", not "text/html".

Check this one for more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51735450/1141936