Button is not working after clicking on "Start Withouth Debugging (Ctrl + F5)"

The button is not working on the webpage. Can someone explain why it's not working?
I used Visual Studio 2022
The environment is in Visual Studio between HTML codes.
Steps I follow:

Added Html code
Added <button type="button" onclick="https://www.google.nl"></button>
Clicked on "Start Without Debugging (CTRL + F5)"
Click on the button on the webpage but the button is not working.


Onclick is for javascript commands, not url

For an example of onclick navigate see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483828/535480

For your NEXT fine question please include the HTML and JavaScript - best even as a snippet that runs right IN the question as a minimal reproducible example.

I find the solution.
Google
